# Magento 2: Best practice create model class

Tags: magento2, database, model, best-practice, dependency-injection

First thing, I have a question on this topic [Optimize load model memory](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206839/magento-2-optimize-memory-leak-perfomance)

Then I have some questions for the best way to create a Model to load or save data to Database?

Could you please explain which of these options are bad and which are better.

**1: Using Factory?**

**2: Using Dependencies?**

**3: Using Repository?**

Or could you please suggest to me some other way that does it better?

Thank for any explanation.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158081/when-should-we-use-a-repository-and-factory-in-magento-2